# Distribution function of $Y$ using $F_X(.)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

How to determine the distribution function of random variable $Y = X^3-6X^2$ in terms of $F_X(.)$.

Since this function is not one-to-one, I couldn't find the solution. How can I solve this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In principle by solving the inequality $x^3-6x^2\leq y$. Not quite easy. For most values of $y$ (unfortunately not all) a $z_y$ exists with $x^3-6x^2\leq y\iff x\leq z_y$ and in that case $F_Y(y)=F_X(z_y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As drhab pointed out, you need some technique to solve a general cubic. Before doing that, lets do some simple calculus to analyze the curve $y = x^3 - 6x^2$ for a better visualization. Note

$$ \frac {dy} {dx} = 3x^2 - 12x$$

so there are two extremum $x = 0$ and $x = 4$. Since the leading coefficient, the coefficient of $x^3$ is positive, we know that the first one $(0, 0)$ is a local maximum and the latter one $(4, -32)$, is a local minimum.

So from the graph we know that $x^3 - 6x^2 \leq y \iff x \leq z_y$ for $y < -32 \text{ or }y > 0$. And for $ 0 \leq y \leq 32$, the solution of the inequality will be in the form of $x \leq z_{y1} \text{ or } z_{y2} \leq x \leq z_{y3}$ where $z_{y1} \leq z_{y2} \leq z_{y3}$.

Next, to really solve $x^3 - 6x^2 - y = 0$, we can follow the standard technique, e.g.
http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/factor/fac11/fac11.html

Let 
$$x = w - \frac {-6} {3} = w + 2$$
to obtain a depressed cubic:
$$ \begin{align} & (w+2)^3 - 6(w+2)^2 - y \\
= &~ w^3 + 6w^2 + 12w + 8 - 6w^2 - 24w - 24 - y \\ 
= &~ w^3 - 12 w - y - 16 \\
= &~ 0 
\end{align}$$

So we transformed the equation into the form
$$ w^3 - 12w = y + 16$$
and we need to find $s, t$ such that
$$ 3st = -12, s^3 - t^3 = y + 16$$
From this we can obtain
$$ \begin{align}  (y + 16 + t^3)t^3 &= -64  \\
\Rightarrow  t^6 + (y + 16)t^3 + 64 &= 0 \\
\Rightarrow t^3 &= \frac {-(y+16) \pm \sqrt{(y+16)^2 - 4\times64}} {2} 
=  \frac {-(y+16) \pm \sqrt{y(y + 32)}} {2} 
\end{align}$$
Here we only need the positive root and thus taking
$$ t = \left(\frac {-(y+16) + \sqrt{y(y + 32)}} {2} \right)^{1/3}$$
$$ s = \left(\frac {(y+16) + \sqrt{y(y + 32)}} {2} \right)^{1/3}$$
and
$$ \begin{align} x &= w + 2 = s - t + 2 \\
&= \left(\frac {(y+16) + \sqrt{y(y + 32)}} {2} \right)^{1/3}
- \left(\frac {-(y+16) + \sqrt{y(y + 32)}} {2} \right)^{1/3} + 2
\end{align}$$
will be a solution to the equation. You can verified that it indeed is the unique real root for $y < -32 \text{ or }y > 0$.

For the middle range $y \in [-32, 0]$, there are 3 real roots and we need to solve them out. The the remaining parts you may check out

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardano's_Formula

and you can try to fill out the details.

Comment: This is not my territory. Nice that it is yours (+1). Caution: I did not check it. I just *believe*  in this sort of cases.